# Preallocating a dataframe in R with date as the column class

Tags: r

I want to preallocate space for dates in an R dataframe.

To preallocate space for characters and numbers, I would write

```
MyDataframe <- data.frame(Name = character(10), 
                          Tickets  = numeric(10))
```

What would I add next to preallocate space for dates?
This does not work...

```
# DOES NOT WORK
MyDataframe <- data.frame(Name = character(10), 
                          Tickets  = numeric(10)
                          Date = Date(10))
```

Currently, I define the column as numeric, then coerce to dates, but this seems less than ideal.
Thanks

Comment: Your second code snippet does not work because you are missing a comma. Even then it would still not work because you are calling a function that does not exist, `Date()`. Finally if you mention something not working, its always helpful to give the error message you actually see. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for tips on how to make a reproducible R question.

Comment: Just had the same question - and went round the same loops trying to find a fun that would pre-allocate for dates.    Useful solution.  I am in general not in favour of filling cells with fake data though.  However it looks like there is no way around it in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you are looking for is a placeholder column with 10 dates, this works:

```
as.Date(1:10, origin=Sys.Date())
```

Your problem is that the `character()` and `numeric()` functions take a length argument, but
`as.Date` (as there is no `Date()` function) does not (`?as.Date`)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my final code.  It works well.

```
MyDF <- data.frame(Name = character(10),
                   Tickets = numeric(10),
                   Date = as.Date(rep(0,10), origin = "1900-01-01"))
```

Here is the output:

```
> MyDF

   Name Tickets       Date
1             0 1900-01-01
2             0 1900-01-01
3             0 1900-01-01
4             0 1900-01-01
5             0 1900-01-01
6             0 1900-01-01
7             0 1900-01-01
8             0 1900-01-01
9             0 1900-01-01
10            0 1900-01-01
```

And the summary

```
> summary(MyDF)

 Name     Tickets       Date           
 :10   Min.   :0   Min.   :1900-01-01  
       1st Qu.:0   1st Qu.:1900-01-01  
       Median :0   Median :1900-01-01  
       Mean   :0   Mean   :1900-01-01  
       3rd Qu.:0   3rd Qu.:1900-01-01  
       Max.   :0   Max.   :1900-01-01
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: I would add the argument `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to `data.frame()`. Otherwise if your `default.stringsAsFactors=TRUE` then character variables will be coerced to Factors with one level and attempts to add values will yield NAs.